# Put the following in rectangular form.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

$$(\sqrt{3}+i)^7$$

My question: $r = 2$. For $\theta$, do I use $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ or $\dfrac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi$? The book uses the former but I thought the latter is more appropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: To clarify, since you're raising it to an integer power, you'll get $\frac{7\pi}{6} + 7\cdot 2 n \pi$. The latter part is just $2 k \pi$ with integer $k$, and thus it doesn't matter when you convert to rectangular form.

Comment: The argument of a nonzero complex number is only defined modulo $2\pi$. But it is unique if you require it belongs to, say, $(-\pi,\pi]$ as one does when one considers the principal branch of the complex logarithm. But all these values of $\theta$ yield the smae number after exponentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt{3}+i)^7=2^7(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i)^7=2^7e^{7i\pi/6}=2^7(\cos\frac{7\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{6})$$